# How to apply a rewrite to the right side of a conditional without splitting on it?

Tags: coq

```
Lemma in_app_iff : forall A l l' (a:A),
  In a (l++l') <-> In a l \/ In a l'.
Proof.
  intros.
  split.
  - induction l.
    + simpl.
      induction l'.
      * simpl. intros. inversion H.
      * simpl.
        intros [HL | HR].
        right. left. apply HL.
        right. right. apply HR.
    + simpl.
      intros [HL | HR].
      * left. left. apply HL.
      * apply or_assoc.
        right.
        apply IHl.
        apply HR.
  - intros [HL | HR].
    + induction l.
      * inversion HL.
      * simpl in HL.
        simpl.
```

---

```
  A : Type
  x : A
  l, l' : list A
  a : A
  HL : x = a \/ In a l
  IHl : In a l -> In a (l ++ l')
  ============================
  x = a \/ In a (l ++ l')
```

I am thinking that if I could somehow apply `IHl` on the right side only, then I could apply `HL` to solve the case but I am not sure how.

If I use split here then I would lose the ability to solve this problem as I would have to prove that `x = a` in the `In a l` branch of the hypothesis and vice versa.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple of notes:

- First, your proof is too long. Think a bit more, in particular see if you are maybe doing too many inductions or splitting in the wrong place.
- Secondly, these kind of rewrites are a bit hard to do, but some of them are possible with "Setoids" and iff. You may be interested in the `or_iff_compat_l` lemma:

  ```
  or_iff_compat_l : forall A B C : Prop, B <-> C -> A \/ B <-> A \/ C
  ```
- Indeed, some libraries prefer to use the Boolean versions of `/\` and `\/` to improve rewriting.
- And lastly, your goal is proved immediately if you destruct `HL`.